# Why Heroku DB always reports at least 3 open connections?

Tags: heroku

My Heroku production database always reports at least 3 open connections:

```
$ heroku pg:info
Plan:        Crane
[...]
Connections: 3
[...]
```

The 3 connections are there even if I scale web dynos to 0 (I don't use worker dynos).

What is the source of these connections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work on Heroku Postgres. Those connections are used by various monitoring systems that help us keep your database alive.

You can `heroku pg:psql` in, and run `SELECT * from pg_stat_activity` to see what connections are currently established.